# How to travel through a Thoqqua's tunnel?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, movement, dungeon

In the 3.5 monster manual, it states

> It burrowing leaves behind a usable tunnel, albeit a small one with blistering hot walls.

What does this mean in terms of game-rules? Would a medium creature be able to squeeze through this tunnel? If so, would it have to make a certain skill check? And what are the effects of the 'blistering hot walls'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of game rules, it means that:

1. there's a visible hole that makes it clear something burrowed through;
2. the hole, being small, can only be navigated by squeezing or by small (in the real world meaning of the word) creatures. A thoqqa is 1ft in diameter, since it moves like worms I expect the hole to be only slightly more bigger. Escape artist checks let anyone whose head is smaller than the hole to pass through it (so it depends on your size and race, DM's call). For reference, *Ring Gates* are 18 inches wide and a small creature can pass through them with a DC 13 escape artist check.
3. the holes are red hot, which means that (at least if the thoqqa has recently dug them) they do fire damage on contact. Since we have no reference for the walls I'd say they do as much damage as touching the thoqqa does. For reference, a fire deals 1d6 fire damage per round to anybody touching it.